# Why is contents of _Layout.cshtml missing when running locally on IIS7.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, localhost

I am testing an mvc4 site locally and have set up my hosts file / IIS so that I can run it from a test domain name. I am following instructions from here: http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/oauth-providers

When I access it via the bound domain set up in IIS it does 'work'... but the entire contents of _Layout.cshtml are missing.  All that displays is the html from the View being called.

When I run the site using the Debugger, or on live hosting it comes up as expected. So I don't think there's any problem with paths, or using ViewStart.

It's only when accessing it via the domain (bound to localhost on IIS) that the _Layout.cshtml content is missing.

Any ideas as to why this might happen and how I can resolve it? Thanks

Comment: pressing F12 (developer tools) in chrome will give you some good hints as to what the cause may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question, but until somebody can offer a better response, it might help others in a similar position.

I had to run the site from VWD using the Debug button - that runs the app on the standard .Net Development Server, which gives you a port number.

Adding that port number to the end of my domain name made my _Layout.cshtml display.

e.g. http://testdomain.com:54829/

Comment: Marking this as answer as nothing new has come forward since.